# NFS Одностороннее копирование данных на клиентские сервера (UBUNTU)

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

Подскажите пожалуйста, с какими опциями можно настроить одностороннее копирование всех данных с главного сервера на клиентские.

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы все данные помещенные на главный сервер, автоматически копировались на другие (клиентские) сервера.

Конфиг: `/etc/exports`

```
/root/files *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Как достичь одностороннее чтение данных без изменения, чтобы клиентские сервера не могли писать, только читать, и чтобы повысить скорость, нужно полностью скопировать все данные из папки в папку клиенту, чтобы он не посылал запросы каждый раз, а физически находил файл у себя на диске.

Comment: Посмотрите rsync. Он как раз предназначен для таких вещей. И NFS ему не особо нужна, он конечно может и с примонтированного диска на свой писать, но его можно запустить например на главном сервере в режиме демона, дав настройки на раздаваемую папку и клиенты эту папку могут синхронизировать периодически

Comment: И да, rsync в качестве демона даже предпочтительнее, чем rsync поверх NFS, так как по NFS ему для сравнения файлов все равно придется их по сети тянуть, а по собственному протоколу - только измененные части

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое, обязательно протестирую `rsync` возможно это будет лучшим решением без NFS, просто NFS я взял когда работал с докером, там как раз и познакомился с ним, ещё вопрос, есть ли `rsync` для `Docker` ?

Comment: rsync это просто программа, входит в состав всех linux-дистрибутивов, запускайте её где и как хотите